# Choices values based on column items of another list in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate

I am creating a PowerApps Canvas App,it has a page which contains an edit form connected to a data source 'Eform'(Sharepoint List). Eform has a choice field called Location. I want the values of the Location field to be dependent on items made in other Sharepoint List(Eform2).
For eg:if in Locate column of Eform2,items are made as UK,US,GEM,etc;they should appear as choices when the dropdown of Location(of Sharepoint list EForm) is clicked.
Also,Locate is a single line text type column
In a holistic view,when my app will be running,the Locations field's values should be controlled externally(and not be hardcoded). how can i go about doing this,perhaps using Power Automate?
Also,i would be open to other ways in the way the changes can be achieved?

I tried Power Automate flows,however they seem to pertain to items and thus dont work.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint fields of type 'Choice' are a bit tricky. If you have a choice like UK, in PowerApps it is represented as a record { value: "UK" }. If you want all choices to appear in a combobox control, use the [Choices()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-choices) function. If you want to filter the selectable values, you can combine it with Filter() like this: `Filter(Choices(..),value="UK")`. SharePoint 'Lookup' and 'Person or Group' fields also work quite similarly. Using a lookup field instead of a choice field could make your app more dynamic.